# Argument to path.dirname must be string: juno-julia-run package

Tags: julia, atom-editor, juno-ide

I installed JuliaPro on my Windows 10 Desktop. Whenever I open JuliaPro, I see a deprecation warning though I have not coded anything.

Please find the below image, for more details.

Will it be a problem if I disable `juno-julia-run` package?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, found an answer in discord.

You should write something and save it as .jl file and then restrart Atom.

The problem would have solved by then